# Can variables be used in a .filter of a queryset

Tags: python, django, filter

What is the correct way of using variables in filters in python/Django? Conceptually, I want to do this:

```
whereconditionfield = 'rate_of_interest'
whereoperator = 'gte'
arri = 50.0
myqsfiltered=myqs.objects.filter(whereconditionfield__whereoperator=arri)
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a dictionary and [*unpack* it into the keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
kwargs = {whereconditionfield + "__" + whereoperator: arri}
myqs.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```